# Batch Normalization vs Full Whitening

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, normalization

In section 3 of the paper [Batch Normalization: Accelerating Deep Network Training by Reducing Internal Covariate Shift, by
Sergey Ioffe and
Christian Szegedy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf), it says

> Since the full whitening of each layer's inputs is costly and not everywhere differentiable, we make two necessary simplifications.

I understand that the full whitening is related to their analysis in section 2, however, I still couldn't figure out the difference between the full whitening and batch normalization. I think they are basically the same -- subtracting the mean from the inputs and then dividing by the variance. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full whitening has an additional first step of projecting the data on eigven-vectors, which requires decomposition of a full covariance matrix computed for the data. For high-dimensional data, this can be very expensive. For additional info, see [this link](http://mccormickml.com/2014/06/03/deep-learning-tutorial-pca-and-whitening/).